# Program Microsoft Office 2007 Word to add a period after double space?

Tags: microsoft-word, iphone

I was wondering if its possible to make Word type like an iPhone. For example, on the iPhone, you press the space bar twice and it adds a period to the sentence. How could you do that in Word?

Comment: I was gonna say you could use the AutoCorrect feature but it doesn't seem to add spaces only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use some Text Expansion software to do that. There is an article from Lifehacker about Text Expansion [here](http://lifehacker.com/#!5611210/how-to-use-text-expansion-to-save-yourself-hours-of-typing-every-day).

I would try [Texter](http://lifehacker.com/#!238306/lifehacker-code-texter-windows) first, as it seems to be the most lightweight and easy to use. First, [download](http://edge-cache.gawker.com/lifehacker/Texter-Installer-0.6.exe) and install the program. Once it's running, press CTRL+SHIFT+H to bring up a window where you add a new expansion rule. Put a space as the 'hotstring', change the replacement text to a period, and then set the trigger to 'space'.

Alternatively, you could put a double space in the 'hotstring' and change the trigger to either 'Enter' or 'Tab', but the first method shouldn't cause any problems.

This also works across all applications, not just in Word!

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that that functionality doesn't exist for any versions of Microsoft Word.

Long answer is that you might be able to create a macro and make it's keyboard shortcut Alt+Shift+. (or whatever you want) and the only thing you would tell the macro to do is type `.`.